# Showing Error by uploading DOC file using JODConveter

Tags: jodconverter

I am trying to convert office file to pdf using JODConveter. i have followed all the steps present in [this link]http://www.artofsolving.com/node/14.html

but  it is showing error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7XQ3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st need to set the path variable of Open office, then open cmd with open office installed location then run a command

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

Use this code in your java project:

```
OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection("localhost",8100);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);

                converter.convert(inputFile, outputFileLoacation);
                long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(input + " =  " + (t2 - t1) + " ms");

            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection.isConnected()) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
```